# Calling ttx in loop causing an error

Tags: python, fonts

I am trying to use [FontTools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fonttools/) to convert otf and ttf fonts to XML.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, sys, fnmatch, re

path = "fonts/"
dirs = os.listdir( path )

for file in dirs:
    print file
    ttx file
```

I get the following error however

> File "listCharacters", line 16
>
> ```
> ttx file
>
>        ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

`ttx` is the command to run the XML conversion. I cannot understand what the problem is here, but this represents my entire experience with this language, so hopefully it is simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change it to

```
os.system("ttx {file}".format(file=file))
```

this will run it in your shell (bash or whatever), there are lots of ways of doing this, this is just one and it is the easiest for new users

`ttx file` is not a python statement , so of coarse you get a syntax error

you can debug it pretty easily

```
cmd = "ttx {file}".format(file=file)
print("RUN:",cmd)
print("CWD:",os.getcwd())
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: Thanks. What is this doing exactly?

Comment: you probably need `"ttx fonts/{file}".format(file=file)`

Comment: yeah, you hit it. that was my problem.